# How to use any and not when searching for items in a list (python)

Tags: python, any

So I'm writing a program to search job postings for keywords.  I already have the code to turn the entire job description into a list of individual words, removing spaces, special characters, made everything lowercase, etc.

I want to do something where I can be like "print something if this list contains `python` but don't print it if it has `python` and `VBA.` Here's what I have:

```
def query_job_posting(url, query_list_include, query_list_exclude): 

    soup = create_soup(url)

    ...list formatting functions...

    for i in job_description_list:
        if any(word in i for word in query_list_include) and not any(exclude in i for exclude in query_list_exclude):
            print(url)
```

`job_description list` looks like this:

```
['this',
 'is',
  'a',
  'vba',
  'job',
  'python']
```

but it doesn't seem to be working.

If `query_list_include=['python']` and `query_list_exclude=[]` then the url prints.

If `query_list_exclude=['vba']` and `query_list_include=[]` then the url does not print.

But If I leave `python` as included and `vba` as excluded, then the url still prints, even though I manually verified both `vba` and `python` are in the `job_descripton_list`

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: What output are you getting, and what did you expect? Please create a [mcve].

Comment: I think you meant to print i, not url

Comment: You can do this easily in a single pass by iterating over your list, keeping a flag for `found_target` and checking for `exclusion` along the way. If you *ever find exclusion*, return `False`, else, return `found_target`. `any` will require you to use two-passes, or maybe some slippery state-mutation...

Comment: Ohhhhh, then I could store `any(word in i for word in query_list_include)` into a variable and check if it's `True` or `False` then proceeed to do the same thing for `any(word in i for word in query_list_exclude)`?

Comment: `@ juanpa.arrivillaga` can you dumb that down for me?  what do you mean by `flag` and `slippery state mutation`?

Comment: All I'm saying is that using `any` forces you to do two passes, or to do stuff that makes your code hard to reason about if you want to do it in a single pass. Just use a for-loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Problem:

You actually look for each word in each element of the list:

```
for e in list:
    if any(w in e for w in include) and not any(w in e for w in exclude):
        print(url)
```

Which does the following:

```
'this'    # do nothing
'is'      # do nothing
'a'       # do nothing
'job'     # do nothing
'python'  # print url
```

You can verify it with:

```
for e in list:
    if any(w in e for w in include) and not any(w in e for w in exclude):
        print(e, url)
```

Which should print `python <url>`.
In this case, having 'VBA' in the list will change nothing

---

#### Solution:

From your explanation you want to do:

```
url = ...

list = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'job', 'python']
include = ['python']
exclude = ['VBA']

if any(w in list for w in include) and not any(w in list for w in exclude):
    print(url)

Out[]: <url>
```

It evaluates the conditions from the `if` statement:

```
'python' in list  --> True
'VBA' not in list --> True
```

Then executes `print(url)`

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for but how can I prevent printing true/false for every words in the list and just get the url?

Comment: You remove the loop through the list - just use the if statement

Comment: @e1v1s: It was just to depict the mechanism, the provided solution will only do `print(url)` if the conditions are met.

Comment: @FabienP, remove the for loop from here? 

`if any(w in list for w in include) and not any(w in list for w in exclude):
    print(url)`

Comment: @e1v1s, You use this without change, it should work as is.

Comment: I had another print statement somewhere else in my code. all good now. thanks!